# CSS select child by type only

Tags: html, css

I have the following code: http://jsfiddle.net/tF8K9/27/

HTML

```
<ul class="master">
    <li class="link"></li>
    <li class="link target"></li>
    <li class="main">
        <ul>
            <li class="link"></li>
            <li class="link target"></li>
            <li class="link"></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="link"></li>
    <li class="link target"></li>
    <li class="link"></li>
    <li class="link"></li>
    <li class="link"></li>
</ul>
```

How can I select only the 3rd and 5th `link` element on the page? I wanted to target the `target` elements dynamically by their position number.

Comment: You can’t, not with `:nth-of-type` alone. You _could_ select them as the 1st and 3rd LI within the child UL if your structure is that static …

Comment: So which items are you hoping to select (it might be a good idea to give them some sort of identification so we can refer to them more easily)?

Comment: @CBroe I don't need to be using the nth-of-type, I just want them selected

Comment: please could you identify in your markup which <li> do you need to target?

Comment: Sounds like you need a :nth-of-class which doesn't exist yet. You could do this with JavaScript though.

Comment: @GEspinha what exactly do you mean with "selected"? Why not add a specific class `.selected` to the elements that need to be highlighted (if that's what you meant with selection)? Perhaps you should rethink the way your page works.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out. [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tF8K9/26/)

```
.master ul li:nth-child(3),.master ul li:nth-child(5){
background:green;
}
```

Comment: You probably didn't understand the question, that is not what I am looking for, thank you anyway

Comment: I got your what you needed. But the way you want it, its either better to have classes added specifically or use jquery methods to get it as desired.